# pass video file from firebase storage to another page based on the data values given to each field inside firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to pass video file from firebase storage to another page based on the data values given to each field inside firestore.
But...
As we all can understand, I got an error.
Correct!
For some reason I get this annoying error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadVid is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onchange

here is the code I used:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var subjectSel = document.getElementById("subject");
    var bookSel = document.getElementById("book");
    var pageSel = document.getElementById("page");
    const IGLink = document.querySelector("#IG_link");

    for (var x in subjectObject) {
      subjectSel.options[subjectSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
    }
    subjectSel.onchange = function() {
      //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
      pageSel.length = 1;
      bookSel.length = 1;
      //display correct values
      for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
        bookSel.options[bookSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
      }
    }
    bookSel.onchange = function() {
      //empty Chapters dropdown
      pageSel.length = 1;
      //display correct values
      var z = subjectObject[subjectSel.value][this.value];
      for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        pageSel.options[pageSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
      }
    }
    
    function uploadVid(files) {
      const storageRef = firebase.storage();
      const videoRef = storageRef.child('subjectSel.value');
  
      const file = files.item(0);
  
      const task = videoRef.put(file)
  
      task.then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot)
        const url = snapshot.downloadURL
        document.getElementById('file-ip-1-preview').setAttribute('src', url)
      })
    }

    // Click submit in add modal
formA.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection('videos').add({
    subject: subjectSel.value,
    book: bookSel.value,
    page: pageSel.value,
    IGLink: IGLink.value,
  });

});


  }
```

```html
    <form action="#" class="login-form" name="Creator Submission">

      <div class="custom-select">
        Subjects: <select name="subject" id="subject">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-select">
        Books: <select name="book" id="book">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please select subject first</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-select">
        Page: <select name="page" id="page">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please select a book first</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <input type="url" id="IG_link" pattern="https://.*" class="ig_li" placeholder="your instagram link:">
      <label for="IG_link"></label>

              <div class="txtb">
          <input type="file" id="file-ip-1" accept="video/mp4" onchange="uploadVid(this.files);">
        </div>


        <div class="preview">
          <video id="file-ip-1-preview" src="">
        </div>


      <input type="submit" class="logbtn" value="Publish">

  </form>
```

I am not sure how to fix the problem or what causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the way you have defined your `uploadVid` function, it is not "visible" to the HTML code where you try to invoke it.  Without seeing how you are importing that JavaScript code into your HTML file, we can only guess as to what change you need to make to the function declaration so that it is in scope of the HTML's `onChange` property.